# API using SignalR with IdentityServer4 hangs on 3+ connections

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, identityserver4, asp.net-core-signalr

My scenario is I have an API that implements SignalR and IdentityServer4. My client is a Vuejs SPA served from a .net-core app. After the vue client has the `access_token` I initiate the signalr connection and save it inside `vuex` store.

This is how I setup my connection:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl(http://example.com + '/notifyHub',
    {
        accessTokenFactory: () => { return token }
    }
).build();

connection.start()
    .then(() => {
        window.console.log("signalR connection successful")
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return window.console.error(err.toString());
    });
```

This is my API configuration of SignalR with IS4 Authentication

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = $"{_config["Server"]}";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = _env.IsProduction() ? true : false;

    options.ApiName = "api";
    options.ApiSecret = "secret";

    options.TokenRetriever = new Func<HttpRequest, string>(req =>
    {
        var fromHeader = TokenRetrieval.FromAuthorizationHeader();
        var fromQuery = TokenRetrieval.FromQueryString();
        return fromHeader(req) ?? fromQuery(req);
    });
});

services.AddSignalR();
//sub claim is used from the token for individual users
services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, UserProvider>();
```

And application

```
app.UseWebSockets();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notifyHub");
});
```

The client always establishes a successful connection, and all the live notifications work as expected.

Now to test the functionality I launch 2 clients, 1 from Chrome and 1 from Firefox, while the two clients are connected everything works.

As soon as try to connect a 3rd client (using Chrome Incognito or IE Edge), the signalr connection is successful but the API hangs for all 3 clients. If I refresh any of the clients the other 2 will resume working, if close one of the clients the other two resume working fine.

There is no valuable info in the logs on the client or the api side to indicate to what is happening.

My question is what can cause this issue and how to do I investigate?

Is this an issue of launching multiple clients from the same host, and will this occurs in production will it just block the single host launching the clients or all of the hosts?

**EDIT**

I changed from localhost to local IP 192.*.*.* to try connect from my mobile browser see if that changes anything, same thing happened, after 3rd client connects the API hangs, If I don't connect to the signalR hub by omitting `connection.start()` I can launch as many clients as I can without breaking.

I am hosting on local IIS at the moment and not IIS express.

Comment: May I ask; I am using all same APIs you seem to be..  I have `accessTokenFactory: () => { return '987654321' }`  I don't see `9887654321` anywhere in `httpContext.Request` serverside(headers nor query string), nor when viewing request in chrome console network.  I see that you have `TokenRetrieval.FromAuthorizationHeader()` and `TokenRetrieval.FromQueryString()` The first request is the negotiate request I am looking at.  Any input?  Will write a proper SO question and link. ~Thx

Comment: Here is linked question of above.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415243/missing-token-when-using-accesstokenfactory-in-signalr-hubconnectionbuilder

Comment: Did you resolve that? (You can answer your own question) :p

Comment: @Benoit I never did. This issue doesn't occur in production though.